# How to wrap a string with a html tag in hyperHTML through RegEx replace

Tags: javascript, regex, hyperhtml

I'm building a search auto-suggest component where the results are rendered with hyperHTML.
The matching string part of the suggestions returned from the server should be highlighted.

I'm using a RegEx and `String.prototype.replace` to highlight the matching part, but somehow I can't manage to output the return value of it to HTML. It just renders the `<strong>` tags as strings.

I tried quite a bit of different approaches to solve this but without any success and am running out of ideas...

This is my rendering function:

```js
const suggestionsContainer = document.querySelector(
  ".js-suggestions-container"
);
const suggestions = [{
    title: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    url: "#"
  },
  {
    title: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    url: "#"
  }
];
let query = "ipsum";

function renderSuggestions(suggestions, query) {
  const queryRegEx = new RegExp(query, "gi");
  hyperHTML.bind(suggestionsContainer)`
      ${suggestions.map((suggestion) => hyperHTML.wire(suggestion)`
        <a href="${suggestion.url}">
          ${hyperHTML.wire()`${suggestion.title.replace(queryRegEx, "<strong>$&</strong>")}`}
        </a>
      `)}
  `;
}

renderSuggestions(suggestions, query);
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperhtml@latest/min.js"></script>
<div class="js-suggestions-container"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to put the tag as `<bold>` instead of `<b>` ? And also I'd suggest rather something like <span style="font-weight:bold;">...</span>  as the b-tag should be used as a last resort.

Comment: @casenonsensitive Yes, you're right. I'd meant to use `<strong>` and not `<bold>`. I edited the post to correct it. But that doesn't change anything about the main problem that the tag is not rendered as html but as a string, regardless of the kind of html tag I use.

Comment: I'm guessing the `a` element is created correctly, so the problem would be inside it. Have you tried making it more easy, replacing the `${wire()\`${suggestion.title.replace(queryRegEx, '<strong>$&</strong>')}\`}` with `${suggestion.title.replace(queryRegEx, '<strong>$&</strong>')}` ?

Comment: @casenonsensitive Yes, tried that as well. Makes no difference. 
I replaced the code example in my original question with a runnable code snippet to make it a bit easier to understand/reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can [see in this CodePen](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/XWXPYKY?editors=0010), the only change you need is to explicitly ask for `html`:

```
  ${suggestions.map((suggestion) => hyperHTML.wire(suggestion)`
    <a href="${suggestion.url}">
      ${{html: suggestion.title.replace(queryRegEx, "<strong>$&</strong>")}}
    </a>
  `)}
```

The `{html: ...}` is the most obvious way, but `hyperHTML` also injects arrays as HTML, but that might be unexpected, while both [lighterhtml](https://github.com/WebReflection/lighterhtml#readme) and [micro html](https://github.com/WebReflection/uhtml#readme) are safer by default, and interpolated content must be always explicitly injected.

P.S. wiring just text as content is also almost never necessary